# Validation::Class and FastCGI don't mix?

Tags: perl, fastcgi, perl-module

I am using the [Validation::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Validation%3a%3aClass) module for form validation in my Perl web app.  However when I tried to switch to FastCGI, the validation stopped working.  Is this a known issue?  Is it common for some modules to not work with FastCGI?  How do I make sure that modules I'm going to use are "FastCGI-safe"?

Comment: By-the-by, that problem no longer exists. Validation::Class was completely re-written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using it as shown in the [Validation without Class](http://p3rl.org/Validation%3a%3aClass#Validation_without_Class) example.
In the "normal" usage, it sets up some necessary stuff when it is compiled, and when used under FastCGI, that only happens once.

I'm not sure how you would generalize looking for other modules that aren't "FastCGI-safe"; this one isn't only because in pursuit of ease of use it has made some assumptions about how it is being used (basically that a given process only uses it in one place and only needs it one time) that seem unlikely to be encountered elsewhere.